# ASP.NET MVC 3 nested lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to the MVC world and need some guidance.  I'm trying to create a vertical multi level menu for a website. The data for the menu is stored in a database table with the following structure:

`ID, categoryName, parentID`

How do I go about this with regular ADO.NET and MVC? As far as I can tell I need to make a `MenuItem` class with `int ID`, `string name` and `List<MenuItem> Children` properties. I then need to make and instance of this class representing the vertical menu and then I need to genereate the HTML for the view.

I have searched the net for an easy to follow example but I'm not finding anything I can understand. If there is anyone out there that can guide me through this it would be very much apprediated!

Comment: First I would find an example of HTML and CSS to create a menu like the one you want. Then I would focus on drafting up the model that would represent a menu item. Finally, work on the View itself which combines the model and the HTML you designed.

Comment: In addition to what @SergioTapia said, since you are storing those menu items into a database, you might also need a tutorial about ADO.NET in order to fetch them. Don't hesitate to ask a specific question if you encounter some difficulties with one of those tasks.

Comment: Right now the only problem I have is figuring out a way to fill the menuItem object recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit your question or split it up into more concrete questions.

I will answer the concrete question in your comment on how to load your MenuItems recursively.

You wrote you use regular ADO.NET. I was free to use dapper in my sample code which makes life a bit easier:

So here is you MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now we open a connection and load the whole `MenuItems` table into a single collection:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
conn.Open();
IEnumerable<MenuItem> allItems = conn.Query<MenuItem>("SELECT * FROM MenuItems");
```

I pretend you will have a single MenuItem as the root item with `ParentId = null`. Lets find it:

```
MenuItem rootMenu = allItems.Single(m => m.ParentId == null);
```

The last thing we have to do is to rearrange the items in a hierachical tree. We do this with a function which works recursively:

```
loadChildren(rootMenu, allItems);
```

Here is the function. It simply looks up the children of the passed item and calls itself on all found childnodes:

```
private static void loadChildren(MenuItem currentItem, 
                                IEnumerable<MenuItem> allItems)
{
    currentItem.Children = allItems
                             .Where(m => m.ParentId == currentItem.Id).ToList();
    foreach (var childItem in currentItem.Children)
    {
        loadChildren(childItem, allItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Thanks everyone for your help on this.